# php - issue in increase days-date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, days

im try to increase days(60) in **m-d-Y** but it is calculate wrong day. it is consider it as **d-m-y** format.

```
echo "Today is :: ".date("m-d-Y"); 
echo "\n";       
echo $DateEnd = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(date("m-d-Y") . ' +60 day'));
```

output is ::

```
Today is :: 11-07-2017
End date is :: 09-09-2017
```

Code : https://3v4l.org/jmT9a

**any help or suggestion will be appreciated**

Comment: You don't need to provide additional `date()` format in `strtotime` See the example https://3v4l.org/RDo5P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause of problem:- [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)  ***Note*** section:-

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

So`m-d-Y` is unrecognised format while adding days to php date.

Do like below:-

```
<?php

echo "Today is :: ".date("m-d-Y"); 
echo "\n";       
echo $DateEnd = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(date("y-m-d") . '+60 days'));
```

Outpit: -https://eval.in/894300

Also check  possible [Php date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It will work for you

```
<?php

echo "Current Date: ".date("m-d-Y");
echo "\n";
echo $contractDateEnd = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(date("d-m-Y") . ' +60 day'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use dateinterval:

```
var_dump (date_create()->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('60 days')));
```

[Test at ideone](https://ideone.com/89jywT)

Answer (score 1):

Read the note from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> **Note:**
>   Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>   To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So you need to use

```
echo date("m-d-Y");
echo "\n";
echo $contractDateEnd = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(date("m/d/Y") . ' +60 day'));
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/894303)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code: it gets the current time (a number) and formats the current date as string then (after it concatenates ' +60 day' to it) it parses it again as number just to format it again as string. A lot of useless and power-consuming operations. And the real trouble is the [custom date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) you use for date and is not supported by PHP for good reasons.

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to handle date & time operations. It is better than the old `date()`, `strtotime()` and the other date & time functions. It can handle multiple time zones, the code is shorter and much clear:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime();
$end->add(new DateInterval('P60D'));

echo "Today is :: " . $now->format('m-d-Y') . "\n";
echo "End date is :: " . $end->format('m-d-Y') . "\n";
```